# Comparing GAM and linear models with without interaction terms

Tags: interaction, generalized-additive-model

I am preparing syntax, using the R mgcv package, to compare the fit of smooth and linear models with and without two interaction terms. There's no data as of yet, I'm just looking for feedback on if my approach is appropriate as I have not done this type of analysis before.

I have four variables: x and y are measured continuous; and z1 and z2 are binary variables. I am interested in if the effect of x on y is curvilinear and if there are curvlinear interaction terms, ie x*z1 and x*z2.

I was thinking of testing this in two steps. In the first step, I was thinking to compare the linear and smooth interaction models:

```
linear_model1 <- gam(y ~ x+z1+z2+x:z1+x:z2, data = data)
summary(linear_model1)
smooth_model1 <- gam(y ~ s(x)+z+s(x,by=z1)+s(x,by=z2), data = data)
summary(smooth_model1)
AIC(linear_model1, smooth_model1)
```

If none of the interaction terms are significant, I would move on to the second step which compares the linear and smooth models without the interaction terms:

```
linear_model2 <- gam(y ~ x+z1+z2, data = data)
summary(linear_model2)
smooth_model2 <- gam(y ~ s(x)+z1+z2, data = data, method = "REML")
summary(smooth_model2)
AIC(linear_model2, smooth_model2)
```

Is this approach appropriate?